# How to call help() from within pdb

Tags: python, pdb

I'd like to have the interactivity of pdb, but also need to use python's help function to introspect objects/methods that I am not familiar with using.

How can I use python's help() from pdb?

everything I try gives me:

```
(Pdb) help(help)
*** No help on (help)
(Pdb) help(list())
*** No help on (list())
```

Comment: I don't think you can unfortunately (it drives me crazy too). I usually have another tab with the interpreter running so that I can call ``help()``.  I really hope I'm wrong and there's a way to do this.

Comment: Related: [python “help” function: printing docstrings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123660/python-help-function-printing-docstrings)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to evaluate an expression using PDB, you use `p`.

```
(Pdb) p help(list)
```

The debugger command docs are here: [PDB Debugger Commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands)

Answer (score 3):

I had problems to get help from pdb too but apparently, inserting `!` before the command does the job like:

```
(Pdb++) !help(help)
```

Comment: Worked for me - Can you reference and authority that indicates this should be the cannonical answer?