# Accessing Python "topic" docstrings with pydoc

Tags: python, pydoc

I understand how Python [docstrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123660/python-help-function-printing-docstrings) work and I regularly use `pydoc.render_doc` to access function docstrings. However, I don't know how to use `render_doc` to access the help topics, e.g. `help("UNARY")`. I don't even know where such a docstring would exist. Is there a way to either *a)* access help topics with pydoc or *b)* an alternative way to capture the help text in a variable?

```
help("UNARY")                         # prints help to console
import pydoc
pydoc.help("UNARY")                   # prints help to console
test = pydoc.render_doc("str")        # writes help to variable

test = pydoc.render_doc("UNARY")      # ERROR
pydoc.help("UNARY")                   # prints help to console
test = pydoc.help("UNARY")            # prints help to console, 'test' is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

pydoc will work in commandline. Use the below command to generate the html documentation for the python modules in the current location.

C:>python  -m pydoc -w sys
wrote sys.html

But pydoc command cannot be used for Keywords and topics

Refer https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/pydoc.py to know the list of topicss and keywords.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm looking for a way to capture the help text in a variable. I don't need a way to get the list of topics and I don't see how running pydoc in the command line helps, especially since you say it can't be used with keywords and topics.