# How to print the docstring(documentation string) of the input function using help()

Tags: python

Write a python script to print the docstring(documentation string) of the input function.
Hint:

- use help() function to get the docstring

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.  SO is not a coding service.

Comment: help(input) worked, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python "help" function: printing docstrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123660/python-help-function-printing-docstrings)

Comment: // , Upvoted because sometimes a duplicate helps get me better search results.

Answer (score 2):

Expected answer is

```
help(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `input` has a docstring so you're looking for this(?):

```
print(input.__doc__)
```

Calling `help` sure does work (python 2 and 3):

`help(input)`

Comment: I need the python script

Comment: That would be the one-liner with the `print` function having `input.__doc__` as its sole argument.

Answer (score -1):

num = input(enter : )
''' hello'''
print(num.**doc**)
  GNU nano 2.9.3                       test.py

def function(l):

```
    '''this is docstring'''
    return l
```

l1 = input('enter name : ')

v = function(l1)
print(f'{function.**doc**} {l1}')